# Google Apps Script - sending e-mails based on IF function

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

I'm having some issues setting up a script in Google Apps. I'm trying to get an e-mail to be sent out whenever a specific number is entered into a cell.

I would like it to work in the following way:

If the number 1 is entered into cell D2 on a Sheet named "Ordered", I would like cell A1 on sheet "Codes" to be sent to the current active user. If the number 2 is entered, I would like cells A1:A2 to be sent; if 3 is entered cells A1:A3 should be sent etc. all the way up to 5 meaning cells A1:A5 should be sent.

I have created a time driven script and written the following however no e-mail is being generated despite the script apparently running with no errors:

```
function sendemail () {

var emailaddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

var vName = s.getName();
var vColumn = r.getColumn();
var vValue = r.getValue();

var row = r.getRow(); 
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ordered");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

var emailAddress = Session.getUser().getEmail(); 
var dataRange = targetSheet.getRange("A1:A10"); 
var emailData = dataRange.getValues();
var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";  

if(vName == "Ordered" && vColumn == 4 && row == 2 (typeof vValue == "number")) { 
 s.getRange(row, 1, vValue, numColumns);
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, emailData);
 s.deleteRows(row, vValue);
 }
 }
```

When I check the Execution transcript the last thing listed is:

```
Range.getValues()
Execution succeeded
```

I'm a complete beginner to all of this so if anyone could help out I would be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you wrote is almost perfect...
This single word (almost) unfortunately made the difference...

the `if` condition was wrong.

try it like this :

```
function sendemail () {

  var emailaddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  var vName = s.getName();
  var vColumn = r.getColumn();
  var vValue = r.getValue();

  var row = r.getRow(); 
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ordered");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

  var emailAddress = Session.getUser().getEmail(); 
  var dataRange = targetSheet.getRange("A1:A10"); 
  var emailData = dataRange.getValues();
  var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";  
  Logger.log(vName+'  '+vColumn+'   '+typeof(vValue));
  if(vName == "Ordered" && vColumn == 4 && row == 2 && typeof(vValue) == "number") { 
    s.getRange(row, 1, vValue, numColumns);
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, emailData);
    s.deleteRows(row, vValue);
  }
}
```

That said, it does not respond to the goal you described in your question about the ranges and values... I guess it was an attempt you made to test the workflow.

Comment: Thanks Serge, I'm struggling with a different part of code now and am struggling to explain it in the comments section so have started a new Question - I hope you can help again!

Comment: ? I guess you sent this link to suggest that I answer it right ?.I'll do  a bit later ;) btw thx for accepting !